# Magento 1.7 - Can't Create Invoice for Check/Money Order Sales

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a Magento store, running on 1.7.0.2.

I am unable to move orders from Pending or Processing to Complete if the payment method is Check/Money Order.

Basically, on the Create Invoice screen, clicking on the [Submit Invoice] button at the bottom of the page does nothing. No errors, no JavaScript warnings, just nothing.

I've tried 3 different browsers, and it's occuring on the live site and on my staging site.

Credit Card orders move to Complete automatically once shipped, Purchase Orders move to Complete by selecting "Capture Offline" when creating an invoice, but still the orders paid for with "Check / Money Order" elude all of my abilities to create an invoice.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: If I copy/paste the URL from the <form> on the Create Invoice page and submit to that URL manually by pasting it into a new window, then the Invoice gets created as expected and the order gets moved into "Complete" status. But *SOMETHING* is preventing the [Submit Invoice] button from actually executing the form submission and I'm not getting any JS console errors.

Comment: we can't just guess whats wrong! can you paste link with admin user password so someone be able to help you !!

Comment: I think you got javascript error. If you are using FireFox, you can check by open `Error Console` by select: `Tools > Web Developer > Error Console`. Also, you can install `FireBug` plugin to FireFox, then enable `Console`, you will see javascript error.

Answer (score 0):

Check payment methods you have enabled in magento admin.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is related to your issue or not, but I had the same issue. After looking at the page source, i saw that there was no onclick event for the submit invoice button.

What i did, which is hardly a solution, but works for me is add another button that adds the correct "onclick" when clicked. I called it "validate invoice".

edit the file /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/invoice/create/items.phtml

at line 124, right above `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('submit_button') ?>`

I added:

```
<button onclick="$$('div .submit-button').invoke('writeAttribute','onclick','$(\'edit_form\').submit()');alert('Done');">Validate Invoice</button>
```

Click "Validate Invoice" button, and then you can submit the invoice.

Again, it's hardly a solution, but it definitely works for me.

Answer (score -1):

What browser and OS are you using? Have had the same issue with a customers of mine, they use Explorer and window. I then tried in Chrome on a Mac and that did the trick.

Comment: I've tried using a number of different browsers. But I can't keep asking the client to switch browsers because some things don't work in Magento when using X browser, and other things don't work when using Y. It's ridiculous.